# ElasticSearch Regex pattern_replace

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a problem. I don’t understand why it works like this?

## My filter pattern

```
'my_pattern_replace' => [
  "type" => "pattern_replace",
  "pattern" => "([0-9.,-]+)\s?(car\b|cars\b|cars\w+)",
  "replacement" => "$1car"
],
```

## test against :

i have 2 cars and 2cars

## String replacement result analyze:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [regular expression syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html):

`([0-9.,-]+)\s?(car\b|cars\b|cars\w+)`

Notice the period you have in the bracketed capture group? A period is a reference for any character (I assume you are looking for a period character instead). You also have a hyphen (or dash) at the end of the bracketed capture group. A hyphen is meant to match anything starting with the character before up to the character after it (e.g. `[a-g]` would match any a, b, c, d, e, f, or g character). Since there is no ending character I am not sure how it would react.

When it is matching and it reaches the "2 cars" (with a space) it is more than likely matching "2 " (2 with a space behind it because of the period in the match). Then replacing it with "2 car" (with the "s" filtered off) which gives you the first "2" and "car" matches (the number and word are considered separate words and are indexed by Elasticsearch as such).

Those characters need to be escaped to capture properly:

`([0-9\.,\-]+)\s?(car\b|cars\b|cars\w+)`

Take a look at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yBZ3NR/1) as a good resource for testing regular expressions as well as the link I provided above for how Elasticsearch is matching with regular expressions.